# Displaying and Searching Date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to display records for release order, and letting the user to search for customer_name and release_date.

I'm getting this error:

> Error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'release Like '%%' ' at line 19"
>    //HTML form
>       
>       
>       
>    //php code for searching
>       $search=$_POST['search'];
>       $search1=$_POST['search1'];

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT order1.order_id,
                     order1.customer_id,
                     order1.release as releasedate,
                     customer1.customer_name as Customer
                     FROM order1 left join customer1 on order1.customer_id=
                     customer1.customer_id

                     where customer_name LIKE '%$search%'
                     And release Like '%$search1%'
                     order by release Asc") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Looks like `$search1` is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

release is mysql reserved word, as can be seen [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

Try to escape you query like this:

```
SELECT 
    `order1`.`order_id`,
    `order1`.`customer_id`,
    `order`.`release` AS `releasedate`,
    `customer1`.`customer_name` AS `Customer`
FROM
    `order1`
    LEFT JOIN `customer1` ON `order1`.`customer_id` = `customer1`.`customer_id`
WHERE
    `customer_name` LIKE '%$search%'
    AND `release` LIKE '%$search1%'
ORDER BY
    `release` ASC
```

I always escapes all table and column names, just for safety. And also is good idea to use one style of writing - in one place of code you have LIKE, in another you have Like - it will help you modify your code in future.